# Can a service worker be updated thanks to a push event?

Tags: service-worker, web-push

I know the question was first raised [here](https://github.com/w3c/push-api/issues/115) and lately discussed [there](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/514):

> I think we should define that:
>
> *[...]*
>
> We do a "update check" any time a SW handles an non-fetch/non-message
>   event, such as events for an incoming push message or geofencing
>   message. These might not trigger a navigation so it's important that
>   these also do update checks.
>
> *[...]*
>
> When we fire an event in the SW, we should trigger a soft update if we
>   haven't done one within 24hrs

The W3C specs are kind of vague to me ([SW Update](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#update-algorithm), [SW Soft Update](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#soft-update-algorithm)), **as of today can a service worker be updated after a push event** ? Are Chrome / Firefox / Safari following the **same behavior** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, the answer is yes. It was implemented here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1207727. You can inspect the changeset, in particular in the ServiceWorkerPrivate.cpp file here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=splinter.html&bug=1207727&attachment=8678641.

Safari doesn't support service workers or the push API, so the answer here is no.